# pygame help in "game function" for loop value is not increasing nor decreasing

Tags: python, pygame, raspberry-pi

I am using a pygame to develop a game that will show two buttons along with an image. The user will have to choose the right button that describes the image. The difficulty I am having that I am not able to increment I variable for the (for loop line 101). I have  noticed the while loop is running infinitely even though I tried brake out of it. When I click on the button, I am not getting the response (correct or wrong as programed in st2 s2t functions)

To summarize I'm trying to capture users responses from the game function and determine whether the user made the right decision or not from st2 or s2t. And go back to the game function and increment I and execute the next elif statement and again call the st2 or s2t and so on.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Sep  7 17:15:42 2020

@author: okand
"""
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Sep  7 17:15:42 2020

@author: okand
"""
import glob
import pygame
import random #we use this to make a random right button
import time 
import os 
pygame.init() # intialize all pygame 

"setting up the display parameters"
display_width = 600
display_height = 600

"setting up the colors and the bright's"
black = (0,0,0)
alpha = (0,88,255)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (200,0,0)
green = (0,200,0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
bright_red = (255,0,0)
bright_green = (0,255,0)


""""Setting display. note the standard we use is 600*600 display limtation"""
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('GUI Speech Recognition') #title of the window
gameDisplay.fill(white)


""" Loading images to the paython from the pic file """
current_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)

image_path = os.path.join('image')
def load_the_image(image):
    images = [
        load_the_image('lalaa.jpg'),
        load_the_image('Ross.jpg'),
        load_the_image('gator.jpg'),
        load_the_image('blue_sea_water.jpg'),
        load_the_image('mountains.jpg'),
        load_the_image('elif.jpg')
   ]


def close():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',30)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    pygame.display.update()
    

    
def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, alpha)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()




""" This function is to set the button parameters x_axis Y_axis width height 
Also, when you hit the button it will take an action """
def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac,(x,y,w,h))

        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()         
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic,(x,y,w,h))

    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)



def s2t():
    carImg= game()
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(0,0))    
    message_display('good job')
    print('good job')
  
def st2():
    carImg= game()
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(0,0))  
    message_display('wrong')
    print('wrong')
    



"""This function is for checking the value i  of the , changes the loaded pictures as well 
as the button options. to get the response s2t & st2 functions are called"""    

def game ():
   aseel = 1
   while aseel == 1: 
       
       for event in pygame.event.get():
        for i in range(1,3):
            

            if i == 1:
                 carImg = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'lalaa.jpg'))
                 gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(0,0))
                 pygame.display.update()
            
                 NewRightButton = 1   #random.randint(1,2)
                 
                 if NewRightButton == 1:
                    button("Dog",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,s2t)
                    button("Cat",50,450,100,50,blue,bright_green,st2)
                    #code that says which the right button is
                    pygame.display.update() 
                    # time.sleep(3)        
                    break  
                 else:
                    button("Cat",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,st2)
                    button("Dog",50,450,100,50,blue,bright_green,s2t)
                    #code that says which the right button is
                    #This makes the buttons swap back and forth
                    pygame.display.update() 
                    # time.sleep(3)
                    break 
                 aseel = aseel + 1
                 print (aseel)
            elif i == 2: 
                 carImg = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'Ross.jpg'))
                 gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(0,0))
                 pygame.display.update()
            
                 NewRightButton = 1   #random.randint(1,2)
                 
                 if NewRightButton == 1:
                    button("ross",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,s2t)
                    button("Cat",50,450,100,50,blue,bright_green,st2)
                    #code that says which the right button is
                    pygame.display.update() 
                    # time.sleep(3)        
                    break  
                 else:
                    button("Cat",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,st2)
                    button("ross",50,450,100,50,blue,bright_green,s2t)
                    #code that says which the right button is
                    #This makes the buttons swap back and forth
                    pygame.display.update() 
                    # time.sleep(3)
                    break 
            elif i == 3: 
                 carImg = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'gator.jpg'))
                 gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(0,0))
                 pygame.display.update()
            
                 NewRightButton = 1   #random.randint(1,2)
                 
                 if NewRightButton == 1:
                    button("gator",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,s2t)
                    button("Cat",50,450,100,50,blue,bright_green,st2)
                    #code that says which the right button is
                    pygame.display.update() 
                    # time.sleep(3)        
                    break  
                 else:
                    button("Cat",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,st2)
                    button("gator",50,450,100,50,blue,bright_green,s2t)
                    #code that says which the right button is
                    #This makes the buttons swap back and forth
                    pygame.display.update() 
                    # time.sleep(3)
                    break 
                 aseel = aseel + 1 
                 print (aseel)
                
            else :
                aseel = aseel + 1
                continue 
            print ('end of the game')
            aseel = aseel + 1
             
        
     
 
                
        
            
def trake_mouse():   #To  track mouse position
    gameExit = False
    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            print (event)

"""" In The main function is to show the first screen with 
two buttons options play or quit. if the user choses quit. the game will quit.
On the other hand, if the user choses to play button. it is going to take him 
to game function  """
def main ():
     while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                 if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        pygame.quit()
                        quit()
        pygame.display.update()
        button("Quit",450,250,100,50,red,bright_red,close)
        button("play",150,250,100,50,green,bright_green,game)
        pygame.display.update()   
     
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.
Posting over 200 lines of code is far too much when you're trying to ask how to handle a variable increment.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Among other things, you've asked multiple questions, without tracing any of the values giving you trouble.

Comment: You dont have to call `pygame.display.update()` that may times. One is enough

Comment: I suggest you look into using classes. Projects like these get really complicated really quickly if you don't have a way of keeping track of everything.

Comment: Why is you  for-loop inside event loop? Put it outside of the event  loop

Comment: You are doing  `carImg= game()` in `s2t` function, then passing `s2t` into `button` as an action which then calls `s2t`. So basically you have game function calling game function, which is unwanted recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that in the inner loop, where you iterate through ranges 1 and 3, you `break` the loop and then try to update `aseel = aseel + 1` afterwards, but it can never happen because you already broke the loop. Same goes for the if statements `if i==2` and `if i==3`: they will never happen because you already broke the loop in the first if-statement.
I'm not entirely sure what this loop does, but if you do the following changes the value `aseel` should update.

```
while aseel == 1: 
   
   for event in pygame.event.get():
    for i in range(1,3):
        
        if i == 1:
             ...
             
             if NewRightButton == 1:
                ...
                # time.sleep(3)        
                # break -> remove this  
             else:
                ...
                # time.sleep(3)
                # break -> remove this 
             aseel = aseel + 1  # should be executed now
             print (aseel)
        elif i == 2: 
             ...
        
             NewRightButton = 1   #random.randint(1,2)
             
             if NewRightButton == 1:
                ...
                # time.sleep(3)        
                # break -> remove this  
             else:
                button("Cat",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,st2)
                button("ross",50,450,100,50,blue,bright_green,s2t)
                #code that says wich the right button is
                #This makes the buttons swap back and forth
                pygame.display.update() 
                # time.sleep(3)
                # break -> remove this 
        elif i == 3: 
             ...
             NewRightButton = 1   #random.randint(1,2)
             
             if NewRightButton == 1:
                ... 
                # time.sleep(3)        
                # break -> remove this   
             else:
                ...
                # time.sleep(3)
                # break -> remove this
             aseel = aseel + 1 
             print (aseel)
            
        else : # it will only loop from 1 to 3, so this case will never happen -> you might as well remove it
            aseel = aseel + 1
            continue 
        print ('end of the game')
        aseel = aseel + 1
```

Also, I want to mention that your implementation in this loop does not make sense, because you're iterating from 1 to 3 and then in each if statement execute something. Why do you need a loop in the first place if all of it will be executed anyways? Also you're updating `aseel` multiple times, and again once you update `aseel` in the first statement, the while-loop should exit and the remaining if-statements will never happen! It seems like you're not entirely sure what to do in this loop. Take a second look at it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The reason I was  updating aseel value was because I wanted to  test why the loop is not changing I value which will change the pictures.